# Can I freeze marinated fish?

Tags: freezing, fish

Today I marinate fish for frying but some pieces of fish is left which is marinated. Can I freeze that marinated fish? I am confused because my mom said that  it can not be freezed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fish generally should be frozen as soon as it's caught. Maybe that's what your mom is referring to?  The marinade itself shouldn't make any difference, unless the fish sat in it a long time, like more than a day.  Hopefully you have been marinating it in the fridge?